# Flutter_How to scrap the data from Javascript in web?

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to get data from javascript in web-site.

It was successful to get data from general html web by using flutter_webscrapper dart package but looks like the webscrapper do not support to load javascript and scrap it.

I've been searching it and lots of developers recommend to use flutter_webview as headless browser.
However, flutter_webview spends too much time to create browser & load website. It takes almost over 4~5 seconds. Seems that challenge to use it in commercial product.

I also cannot use flutter_puppeteer because it does not support android & ios.

If there are any other way or other Dart package to scrap the data from javascript in web-site, please let me recommend. Waiting for your supports.

Comment: I doubt there is any option for dynamic content scraping beyond webview

Comment: Scrap using WKWebView in iOS native(Swift) was so fast but..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to collect data from website or (web scraping) via flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75026492/how-to-collect-data-from-website-or-web-scraping-via-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [web_scraper](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper) package .

may be using  getAllScripts or getScriptVariables methods help you .

this [sample repository](https://github.com/esmaeil-ahmadipour/Flutter_Web_Scraper) used web_scraper package .

Comment: Thanks, Esmaeil. It is faster than others but it still takes  >2 secs. I think it is radical issue of Flutter. Anyway, I found other solution in this case.  I could find CRUD logic in html codes of the site and get data through GET & POST command.